# Bootstrap glyphicon image is sideways above text (using Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a navbar of glyphicons dynamically with jquery, but the glyphicons images are appearing sideways for some reason. I'm appending a navbar to a div like so:

```
$('#divID').append('<div id="buttonList">'+
   '<div id="buttonContainer" class="container">'+
         '<div>'+
            '<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left" id="buttonsGoHere">'+
                 '<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> ('+ divName +')</button></li>'+
             '</ul>'+
          '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
 '</div>');
```

The glyphicons appear but the trash icon is sideways above the text (which is (divName)). What am I missing here to fix this?

EDIT:

css information - I am appending these navbars to divs, here is the div and the buttonlist css.

```
#divID {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
}

#buttonlist {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 1px;  
   width: 4%;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: seems to work [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZXJXdMFqErLOAVqpHRa?p=preview). Maybe a problem somewhere else in the CSS?

Comment: Strange, I guess some other css is warping the image. I'll go looking, thanks for the comment Sir Neuman. I don't need any further answers, as its on my end.